# How to list the deleted contacts by Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to do a sync action in my client side, so need to know how to get all deleted contact list.

By the api (GET /me/contacts), I could get all contact list
But it wastes much time when the user has large contacts.

This api (GET /me/contacts/{id}) tell us the contact is exist or not.
it is inefficient to check every contacts are deleted or not for me.

Which apis do I use? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the [delta query preview](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview) in the `/beta` endpoint? That should do what you want.

Comment: It works for me perfectly. Just use api (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contactFolders/[contactFoldersID]/contacts/delta?)   and save the delta token for the next round

Answer (score 0):

More efficient way for you to check which contacts were removed is getting just the list of contact ID's and then doing the diff between list of ID's returned by graph, and local list.

You can use query parameters to retrieve just the ID's of the contacts, instead of getting the whole objects.

Method url:
    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$select=id

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
It's inefficiency, because it is still do a total contact list to compare.