# List Deleted Contacts Microsoft Outlook Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Endpoints listed in api documentation:

> /me/contacts

> /me/ContactFolders/{folderName}

don't show deleted contacts.

How can I list all deleted contacts?

Comment: Does this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132111/how-to-list-the-deleted-contacts-by-microsoft-graph-api) help you?

Comment: Not at all, because /me/contacts doesn't return deleted contacts.

Comment: Have you looked into this [delta implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/contact-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)?

Comment: Yes, there wasn't any of deleted contacts.

Comment: After a long research I understood that for the deleted contacts there is no such Microsoft Graph API yet. Please see this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684575/how-to-restore-deleted-mail-from-office-365-using-microsoft-graph-api).

Comment: Please raise a uservoice in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that it may be implemented by product team in future.

Comment: Moving this to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research I understood that for the deleted contacts there is no such Microsoft Graph API yet. Please see this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684575/how-to-restore-deleted-mail-from-office-365-using-microsoft-graph-api).

Please raise a uservoice in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that it may be implemented by product team in future.